# Replacing std::bind with lambda with a member function to fill vector of function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I have implemented function pointer list that i want to past the `function` and the `object` i want to convert the bind to a lambda function but i failed, any help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Red {
public:
    template <typename F, typename M>
    void addToVector(F f, M m)
    {
        list.push_back(std::bind(f, m));
        cout<<"Function added.";
    }
    
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> list;
};

class Blue {
public:
    Blue()
    {
        r.addToVector(&Blue::someFunc, this);
    }

    void someFunc(){
        cout<<"Some print.";
    }
    
    Red r;
};


int main()
{
    Blue b;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried this `list.push_back([=](){ return m->f(); });`

Comment: I advocate sticking with bind here. The lambda doesn't give you anything and `bind` is built to handle member function pointers and regular function pointers.  Your lambda will only be able yo handle one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried this `list.push_back([=](){ return m->f(); });`

The correct syntax to call the member function using a pointer to object would be:

```
//----------------------------vvvvvv------->correct way to call member function using a pointer to object
list.push_back([=](){ return (m->*f)(); });
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/u27g6lPFx)

Comment: Thank you! can i use the same syntax `for (auto&& func : list) { func(); }` to invoke the function pointers?

Comment: @AlineMee Yes you can. See [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/JFeG4yJhL) where i've used `b.r.call();` and `for (auto&& func : list) { func(); }` to call the member function `someFunc` and on the screen you'll see the output `Some print called.`

Comment: Perfect! i was thinking i could use something like this `(m->*f)()` in the for loop as well.